# Compare two elements for equality in Prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

In jquery it is very simple to check if two jquery elements are the same:

```
if ($(element1).is($(element2))) alert('yay, $(element1) === $(element2)');
```

What is the equivalent to .is() in Prototype? I have to use Prototype 1.6.1 so an answer that works i this slightly older version would be great :)

Answer (score 2):

=== means "exactly like", so that will work without Prototype.

```
if(var1 === var2) {
  alert("Yay!");
}
```